# How to write a request/response object from angular.js to jax-rs

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jax-rs

I am building my backend and I need to be able to exchange a request/response object from angular.js to my backend (JAX-RS, Jersey).

My backend currently looks like this:

```
@POST
@Path("/search")
@ApiResponses(value = {@ApiResponse(code=200,message="returns results"),
               @ApiResponse(code=404,message="not found")})
@Produces({ "application/json" })
public Response getPostShop( 
        @QueryParam("keyphrase") String keyphrase,
        @QueryParam("product") String product,      
        @QueryParam("priceRange") List<Double> priceRange,
        @Context SecurityContext securityContext) 
    throws NotFoundException {  
    SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest();
    searchRequest.setKeyphrase(keyphrase);
    searchRequest.setProduct(product);
    searchRequest.setPriceRange(priceRange);
    //do something with the "searchRequest"
    return Response.ok(searchResponse).build();
}
```

Angular.Js (Something like this)

```
response.compose = function(searchRequest) {

        return $http({

            method: 'POST', //or GET
            url: '/search',
            data: {
                searchRequest : searchRequest
            },
            headers: {'Content-Type':'application/json'}
        });
    }
```

where `searchRequest`:

```
 $scope.searchRequest = {
                'keyphrase' : $scope.keyphrase,
                'product' : $scope.product,
                'priceRange' : $scope.priceRange,
        };
```

NEW GET request:

```
@GET
@Path("/testkeyphrase")
@ApiResponses(value = {@ApiResponse(code=200,message="returns results"),
           @ApiResponse(code=404,message="not found")})
@Produces({ "application/json" })
@Consumes({ "application/json" })
public Response getTestKeyphrase( 
        @ApiParam(value="keyphrase that the user searches for..", required=true) TestSearchRequest testSearchRequest,           
        @Context SecurityContext securityContext) 
throws NotFoundException {      
    String kyphrase = testSearchRequest.getKeyphrase();
    return Response.ok(testSearchRequest).build();
}
```

and the TestSearchRequest is:

```
public class TestSearchRequest {

    public TestSearchRequest(String keyphrase) {
        this.setKeyphrase(keyphrase);
    }

    private String keyphrase;

    public String getKeyphrase() {
        return keyphrase;
    }

    public void setKeyphrase(String keyphrase) {
        this.keyphrase = keyphrase;
    }

}
```

What I need is instead of receiving all the individual parameters, to receive directly the `searchRequest` object and send back the SearchResponse object respectively (in JSON). Also I need the parameters to be in the body of the request and not in the URI. 
Any ideas?

Comment: `public Response getPostShop(SearchRequest request)`. But POST should be used to create stuff, not for searching stuff. A GET, with query parameters, is what you should use for search.

Comment: Thnx JB I ll give it a try. Thing is that I dont want to expose the parameters in the URI, This is why I am using POST. Is it a good rationale or am i missing something?

Comment: Why do you care about exposing the parameters? Why would the parameters be exposed anyway, since I doubt people will use the REST API directly from their browser.

Comment: Probably you are right. And what would the angular side look like? I edited my question and included a sample request in angular

Comment: Are you asking how to pass query parameters with $http? If so, use params. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#usage

Comment: Thnx I ll have a look at that. so I actually try your example but I keep getting an empty object.